# Ubuntu 17.04 with MariaDB-10.2.11 unable to update 1 table (only) from remote php script

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, php-fpm, mariadb

first let me introduce my setup

2 servers
1. for web, with apache (php7) and nginx(php7-fpm) + local mysql (ubuntu 16.10)
2. mysql MariaDB-10.2.11 server for server 1 (ubuntu 17.04)

The first server is running on the end of it's IO performance so I decided to put server server 2 to host the mysql + some static hosted files over nginx

Now the part I'm lost and the question. After moving the database to server 2, then I'm completely unable to update and insert rows in one of the tables `content` (and so par  the only one I'm aware of having this issue). And here is the weird part: doing insert|update from any other client, like the SqlYog and remote as local mysql client works fine

Any suggestions for what and how to fix this?
What I've tried:
unlock_tables;
reinstalled the entire server 2
repair tables
renamed the table and transfered it again in different ways
tested the script from a local install, same
tested the script to connected,update,insert to a third db

all other search and lookup seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue :/
had to add

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

to my.cnf and that killed the performance a lot, so any suggestion how to get the speed back up?